# como se puede lograr cargar una imagen al seleccionar el item dentro de un TREEVIEW

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Aqui les muestro un ejemplo: al seleccionar el item del TREEVIEW regleja una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que intentaste para lograrlo? Que te traba? Ten en cuenta que las preguntas donde el autor no demuestra ningún esfuerzo en intentar resolverlas no suelen ser bien recibidas. Además, nosotros no damos recomendaciones de recursos externos, ya que dichas respuestas serían basadas en opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Por tal de realizar el efecto de focus que buscas y poner el fondo azul sobre el item seleccionado, además de cambiar el color del texto de negro a azul, puedes utilizar la siguiente plantilla que te adjunto más abajo.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

......
[CODE]
......

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("alt")
style.configure("Treeview",
    background="silver",
    foreground="green",
    )
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#BFBFBF'), foreground=[('selected', 'black')])
```

Como ya comentas, tu ya tienes la lista creada por lo que es innecesario comentar esta parte de código donde se crea la lista y le damos los valores del color de fondo de la lista y el color de las letras *(foreground)*:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("alt")
style.configure("Treeview",
    background="silver",
    foreground="green",
    )
```

Lo importante para cambiar el color de fondo y color de texto sobre el item seleccionado de la lista utilizaremos el "atributo" `.map` sobre la variable `style` -> `style.map()` de la siguiente forma:

```
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#BFBFBF'), foreground=[('selected', 'black')])
```

En esta configuración de atributos, declaramos el fondo del item seleccionado con `background=[('selected', '#BFBFBF')` y el color del texto con `foreground=[('selected', 'black')]` donde tan solo has de cambiar los valores del color *(#BFBFBF y black)* por los que tu quieras.

Comment: De todas formas, ten en cuenta el comentario que te ha dejando @Dante S. para la proxima vez que hagas una question. La idea es que intentes realizarlo por tu cuenta y cuando no tienes mas opción realizar tu pregunta pero siempre adjuntando el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Si tienes alguna otra pregunta o la respuesta no soluciona tu problema hazmelo saber. Un saludo @wally

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3217#3217

Comment: Gracias por tu intención c: Pero te recomiendo evitar responder preguntas de este tipo. Además de que tu respuesta podría no ser bien recibida, promueves la falta de esfuerzo. Y eso también perjudica el aprendizaje del OP.

Comment: Gracias x eso @RuthIsRoot pero no era lo q necesitaba, guardare ese codigo, lo que realmente necesito es poder enlazar el TEXTO de lista con una imagen que se reprodusca como en la foto que comparti. espero que se entienda mejor ahora.

Comment: @DanteS.  You can go after whatever you want, you just cannot deny anyone else to go after what they want. You don't have to do it the way everybody has done it. by Simon Sinek